# Deploy Mercurial with SFTP/SSH

Tags: deployment, mercurial

Currently I am using sourcetree to manage my repo's. I've read about using different branches for 3 stages of website development. I've seen sites like deployhq.com and beanstalkapp.com. I am curious is there a "free" way to deploy/rollback and publish via sftp/shh to my web servers both staging and live production for each of my repo's. I need a way for junior level developers to easily be able to do it too, be great if there was a review process. If there is no free method, what;s the best paid method out there. I also use bitbucket.org to store my repos. 
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a lightweight deployment tool such as [Kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net) (self-promotion). Kwatee is free and can deploy any files via a web interface or python scripts (also ant/maven if you use java). All you'd have to do is to automate the check-out of your branch and then trigger the deploy command in kwatee which will use ssh/scp or telnet/ftp behind the scenes to update your deployment (only changes will be deployed).